# Oque é a track listing e grid track no grid layout?

Tags: css, grid

Li a documentação da mozilla porém não consegui entender muito bem oque seria o grid track e nem o track listing, alguém poderia explicar de uma forma mais simples e intuitiva oque seria isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Grid Tracks**

Definimos linhas e colunas no nosso grid com as propriedades `grid-template-columns` e `grid-template-rows`. Isso define o ***grid tracks***. Um *grid track* é o espaço entre duas linhas em um grid. Na imagem abaixo você pode ver um *track highlighter* – o track na primeira linha do nosso grid.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Grid track** is a generic term for a `grid column` or `grid row`

---

```
none | <track-list> | <auto-track-list>
```

Essas propriedades especificam, como uma **track-list** separada por espaço, os nomes das linhas e as funções de dimensionamento do Grid. A propriedade `grid-template-columns` especifica a lista de tracks para as *Columns*, enquanto a `grid-template-rows` especifica a  **track-list** para as *Rows*.

Grids grandes, com muitas tracks podem usar a notação repeat() para repetir todas ou uma seção de **track listing**. Por exemplo a definição de grid a seguir:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

**Documentação oficial W3C:** https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#track-list

**Fonte:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout